# How can I clear html 5 client storage?

Tags: html, client, local-storage

For example I think StackOverflow remembers users via html 5 client storage.  **How can I clear this storage**?  Clear cache doesn't seem to do it.  Deleting flash cookies doesn't seem to help either.

p.s. I'm using Safari but I'm also interested in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow uses a cookie.  I believe it's the one named "usr".

If you're just trying to clear your stack overflow cookie, delete that one.  Of course, safari is a nightmare around cookie handling so you might just need to use a real browser.

If, however, your interest is really in html 5 local storage then you might want to rephrase the question.  For safari (5/windows) I believe you click on the little gear icon in the top, go to preferences, then security.  Then click on "show databases" and remove away..  But to iterate the point, SO doesn't use those.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browsers cache. Remember that Storage is only stored in the browser you are using at that time.  That always works for me In Firefox and Chrome. Clear then close the browser and reopen

Answer (score 1):

In Safari open the Web Inspector and click on the Storage tab, then find the stuff you want to delete and right-click on it and select Delete.

If you want to clear it for all sites, I'd imagine that the Safari > Reset Safari... dialog would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing cache wont help. I had a similar issue. [How to clear HTML5 data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605015/how-to-clear-html5-data)

I was asked to try out [Clear Console](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/clear-console/). Thankfully It works.

But if you clear cookies, I believe your local storage also disappers. Not sure. I found it when i isntalled some addons but i might be wrong