# How to clear HTML5 data?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I clear html 5 client storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911616/how-can-i-clear-html-5-client-storage)

Could someone suggest a way to clear HTML5 storage quickly ? I've have been working on something which needs me to clear the local storage quite a lot of times. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have posted my answer there as well, incase if it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Clear Console](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/clear-console/).
It clears HTML5 storage.

Comment: I have tried some addons but they clear the cookies too along with it. I need to clear ONLY the html5 storage. Would this help ?

Comment: You can choose to clear either only html5 data or both hmtl5 data and cookies ( along with many other features). So yeah it should help.